# Failed to decode downloaded font in Chrome after installing node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, font-awesome

My login page was working fine before i installed node js on my  PC. 
But now i have the issue below and my login page cannot load load the icons from local resources. I have tried to delete the fonts and copy again but still not lucky.

If i open my login page only then it works normally. I'm using Spring Boot for my application

```html
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/font/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff
login:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/font/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff
login:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.1.0
login:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0
login:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/font/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff
login:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/font/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - what does installing node.js have to do with this? Node.js is not a server, it's just a JS engine with a full system API, so... what were you running before, and how, and what are you running now, and how, to have something exist on localhost:8080?